# Leaflet zoom not working for no reason

Tags: javascript, types, maps, leaflet

I am having a few problems with leaflet zoom for seemingly no reason.

I have written the following function.

```
function set_view(lat,lon,min_zoom)
{

    var zoom = current_map.getZoom();
    alert(typeof zoom);



    if(typeof min_zoom != 'undefined')
    {
        if(min_zoom>=zoom)
        {
            zoom = min_zoom;
                        alert(typeof zoom);
        }
    }


    current_map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lon),zoom);

}
```

Essentially if i pass in a min_zoom value I get the first alert which states that the current zoom is a number, then I get a second alert saying that the min_zoom passed is also a number. I.E Both are the same type.

If I have a min_zoom passed in, my view is set but at full zoom and with no zoom controls working.

If i do not pass a min_zoom value my map is shown perfectly at the current zoom level.

This makes no sense. The exact same value from two different places gives two different results..

Why is this not working and instead breaking the map if a min_zoom is passed?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the entire details of your problem, but you can have Leaflet enforce minimum zoom levels for you. With your L.Map, you can specify the 'minZoom' option, specifying your zoom level. That L.Map will pass this minimum zoom level down into all layers it contains.

Answer (score 2):

`current_map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lon),zoom);`

has a typo.

**L.LatLng()** should be **L.latLng()**